# Given an array of strings, convert each string into: uppercase if first letter is capital lower case if first letter is small

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, if-statement

Given an array of strings, convert each string into:

uppercase if first letter is capital,
lowercase if first letter is small.

`var arr = ['This', 'is', 'My', 'first', 'piece', 'OF', 'javaScript'];`

**Result** The variable `arr` should be now:

`["THIS", "is", "MY", "first", "piece", "OF", "javascript"]`

Comment: Hi Waqar. Welcome to posting on Stack Overflow! Unfortunately, this question is getting downvoted because no code has been posted that attempts to solve it. [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: It was also downvoted because it seems you ask someone to do your homework.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var arr = ['This', 'is', 'My', 'first', 'piece', 'OF', 'javaScript'];

arr.map(e => e[0].toLowerCase() == e[0]? 
  e.toLowerCase():e.toUpperCase());
```

Comment: Consider adding some explanation of the code. Code-only answers may be flagged for deletion as low quality.

Answer (score 0):

The forEach method could help the below code will help you understand

```js
const cpaital = (arr) =>{
    let total = []
    if(arr != null){
        error = false
        arr.forEach(element=>{
            let firstLetter = element.slice(0,1)
            if(firstLetter != firstLetter.toUpperCase()){
                total+= `${element.toLowerCase()}, `
            }else{
                total+= `${element.toUpperCase()}, `
            }
        })
    }else{
        error = true
        errorMessage = "Please fill the arr perimeter."
        return errorMessage;
    }
    return total
}

// Calling Fucnction
console.log(cpaital(['hELLO', "Hello"]));
```

Answer (score -1):

Simple loop and toUpperCase comparison approach:

```
const result = ['This', 'is', 'My', 'first', 'piece', 'OF', 'javaScript']
.map(i => i[0].toUpperCase() === i[0] ? i.toUpperCase(): i.toLowerCase())

// ["THIS", "is", "MY", "first", "piece", "OF", "javascript"]
```

Without `.map`:

```
var result = [];
for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  if (arr[i][0].toUpperCase() === arr[i][0]) {
    result.push(arr[i].toUpperCase());
  } else {
    result.push(arr[i].toLowerCase());
  }
}
```

Comment: any other method using if statement and loop ?? as i have not studied .map and it is not allowed to use.

Comment: @WaqarAnwar I added version without `.map` for you